# How to delete all lines containing more than a certain number of letters?

Tags: bash

How can I delete all of the lines in a file which contain more than a given number of letters? E.g.

```
bear
rabbit
tree
elephant
```

If I restrict it to words of 5 letters or less, the output would be:

```
bear
tree
```

- The file contains various foreign characters, each of these should count as one letter.
- Punctuation symbols also can count as one letter.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/355321/linux-shell-command-to-filter-a-text-file-by-line-length

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
$ awk 'length<=5' input.txt
bear
tree
```

Answer (score 9):

The following would do the trick:

```
sed -i '/^.\{5,\}$/d' FILE
```

What that means is this:

Delete (`/ [...] /d`) in-place (`-i` switch) all lines matching the following pattern:

- line beginning (`^`)
- followed by any character (`.`) repeated 5 or more times (`\{5,\}`)
- followed by line ending (`$`)

from the file named `FILE`.

Answer (score 4):

```
grep -v '......' myfile.txt
```

will deliver lines five characters or less.

It does this by "selecting" lines containing six characters or more, then reversing the action with `-v`, to only print out those that *don't* match.

Comment: `grep -Ev '.{6,}'` is more general and golfs identically in this case. It is however faster to type 6 dots than `.{6,}`.

Answer (score 1):

"The file contains various foreign characters, each of these should count as one letter."
Assuming your input data is in UTF8, this bash filter script should do it.

```
#!/bin/bash
function px {
 local a="$@"
 local i=0
 while [ $i -lt ${#a}  ]
  do
   printf \\x${a:$i:2}
   i=$(($i+2))
  done
}
(iconv -f UTF8 -t UTF16 | od -x |  cut -b 9- | xargs -n 1) |
if read utf16header
then
 px $utf16header
 cnt=0
 out=''
 while read line
  do
   cnt=$(($cnt+1))
   if [ "$line" == "000a" ]
    then
     if [[ $cnt -le 5+1 ]] ; then
      out=$out$line
      px $out
     fi
     cnt=0
     out=''
   else
    out=$out$line
   fi
  done
fi | iconv -f UTF16 -t UTF8
```